# MariaDB SQL WITH RECURSIVE AND UPDATE INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, mariadb, recursive-query

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS(
SELECT 1 AS b, 10 AS a

UNION ALL
SELECT b+1, a+10 FROM CTE WHERE b < 5 )

UPDATE uptable a
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT b,a
   FROM CTE 
) c
ON a.a = c.b
SET a.a = c.a
```

Table:

```
UPTABLE(
a INT
)
```

data 1,2,3,4,5

An SQL syntax error occurs.

> EverSQL SQL Query Syntax Check & Validator this query valid

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT VERSION();` If it is less than 10.2.2, then your instance of MariaDB does not support `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Comment: version 10.4.18-MariaDB-1:10.4.18+maria~focal

Answer (score 1):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/ shows syntax reference:

```
WITH [RECURSIVE] table_reference [(columns_list)] AS  (
  SELECT ...
)
[CYCLE cycle_column_list RESTRICT]
SELECT ...
```

It supports using a CTE before `SELECT` but not before other SQL statements, such as `UPDATE`.

Some other SQL implementations support CTE syntax followed by `UPDATE`, including [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html), [Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [Informix](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10/14.10?topic=statements-statement-common-table-expressions)...

MariaDB apparently implemented a subset of the functionality.