# SQL executed under MySQL V8 works fine but not under version MariaDB V15

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have this SQL :

```
WITH
  randomised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    (SUM(FLOOR(RAND() * 1.5) + 1) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC)) DIV 4 AS offset
  FROM
    products
)
UPDATE
  products
INNER JOIN
  randomised
    ON randomised.id = products.id
SET
  products.created_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL randomised.offset DAY), products.updated_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL randomised.offset DAY)
;
```

This works fine under MySQL version 8 but under MySQL version 15 gives me the following error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE
> products
> INNER JOIN
> randomised
> ON randomised.id = products...' at line 10

is there some thing i need to change to have a backward compatibility to fix this ?

Comment: What is Version 15? Can you be more specific about what you mean by "V15"?

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` on the instance that isn't working?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276025/mariadb-sql-with-recursive-and-update-inner-join/67276257#67276257

Comment: There's no MySQL 15. Check the version.

Comment: MariaDB <> MySQL.

Comment: v15 is the version of the sql client (probably you are using CLI). I think @BillKarwin has nailed the problem with his duplicate link.

Comment: If that's the explanation, then it's a good concrete example of why we should stop thinking of MariaDB and MySQL as compatible variants. They are not drop-in replacements for each other, because they have a significant number of incompatible features, and that number is growing over time.

Comment: @tadman @TheImpaler 
My bad i confused MyQSL with MariaDB.

When i run `SELECT VERSION();` it gives me `10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`

When i run `mysql --version` it gives `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: MariaDB is a fork from MySQL, but since then they have diverged. You should treat them a different platforms and not expect complete compatability. If you check each platform's manual, you'll see that the update syntax varies. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code adapted to MariaDB...

- CTE moved to be a sub-query
- `offset` renamed to `offset_days`

```
UPDATE
  example
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) + 3) DIV 4 * 4   AS offset_days
  FROM
    example
)
  randomised
    ON randomised.id = example.id
SET
  example.created_at = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL randomised.offset_days DAY)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/y2KQyCTx

***Note:**
Do not expect all code that runs on MariaDB to run on MySQL, or vice versa. MariaDB should be treated as an Entirely separate platform, as you would treat Oracle; who happen own MySQL but not MariaDB.*

***It is not a backwards compatibility issue.***